# PHP PDO - Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined when using RLIKE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a simple MySQL table with a `text` field.

I can do this search direct in MySQL to search for an exact phrase (I don't want to use a full text index hence this approach):

```
select * from tbl_log_days where post_content RLIKE '[[:<:]]the office[[:>:]]'
```

That works fine in MySQL, and returns any text containing that exact phrase.

I'd like to include the same in a search form using PHP.

I have my parameterized query set up in PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID
             , post_date
             , post_content
             , post_cat_id
             , post_label
          FROM tbl_log_days
         WHERE post_content RLIKE '[[:<:]]:exact_text[[:>:]]'
      ORDER BY post_date";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':exact_text', $str);
$stmt->execute();
```

However, when I run this, it error with:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\data\php\public_html\diary\search.php:424
```

If I change the SQL to:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID
             , post_date
             , post_content
             , post_cat_id
             , post_label
          FROM tbl_log_days
         WHERE AND post_content = :exact_text '
      ORDER BY post_date";
```

It works fine.

The problem appears to be related to the `'[[:<:]]:exact_text[[:>:]]'` syntax used with RLIKE.

Is there any way I can escape the special characters in RLIKE?

Comment: What if you use `?` as a placeholder?

Comment: Why do you use regular expression pattern matching in this case? Wouldn't `LIKE '%the office%'` suffice in this case?
In any case you should be able to overcome this by using something like `RLIKE ':exact_text'` and then incorporating the brackets in the `bindParam` statement.

Comment: @rolfv1 because `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` match boundaries of the word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, enclosing something in quotes in a query does not make it a placeholder.

So, you don't have any placeholders in your query. Fix (as already noticed in comments) is:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID
             , post_date
             , post_content
             , post_cat_id
             , post_label
          FROM tbl_log_days
         WHERE post_content RLIKE :match
      ORDER BY post_date";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
// use bindValue as you pass a value, not a variable
$stmt->bindValue(':match', '[[:<:]]' . $str . '[[:>:]]');
$stmt->execute();
```